# Remove images from uiimageview.animationimages - iPhone/Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, animation

I'm looking to animate a series of images on the iPhone.  The images are named in consecutive order( image1, image2, image3, etc...).  I'm looking for the best way to animate these images without having to put them into an array.

I have multiple sets of images that will be chosen at random.  Each image set is ~100 frames, so to put all of these in arrays when the app launches, would mean that there are ~1000 images sitting in memory.

In addition to using so much memory, constantly updating UIImage.animationImages can take a little longer than I would like when working with arrays of this size.  I guess what I'm looking for is something similar to what the watch kit has, where it allows you to "setImageNamed(), and then startAnimatingWithImagesInRange().

Edit:

Sorry if my initial post was not as clear as I thought it was.  I tried to avoid posting code for this since I have tried this in Xcode in about 10 different ways, none of which work exactly how I would like.  I have posted my code below, and my issue with this is that the memory continues to fill up every time I animate and the Arrays are staying full when I try to clear them.  For what its worth, I'm really new at this, so I expect I'm missing something very obvious, but I do make sure that I try and figure it out on my own before coming here or anywhere else, its the only way to learn.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewOutlet: UIImageView!

var phaseArray: [UIImage] = []
var optionArray: [UIImage] = []
var outroArray: [UIImage] = []
var randomOption32: UInt32 = 1
var randomOption = 1
var buttonPressed = false

@IBAction func testButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if buttonPressed == false {

        fillPhaseArray()
        fillOptionArray()
        fillOutroArray()
        imageViewOutlet.animationImages = phaseArray + optionArray + outroArray
        imageViewOutlet.animationRepeatCount = 1
        imageViewOutlet.startAnimating()

        buttonPressed == true

    } else {

        clearArrays()
        fillOptionArray()
        fillOutroArray()
        imageViewOutlet.animationImages = phaseArray + optionArray + outroArray
        imageViewOutlet.animationRepeatCount = 1
        imageViewOutlet.startAnimating()

    }


}




func fillPhaseArray() {

    for var i = 1; i <= 65; i++ {

        phaseArray.append(UIImage(named: "phase1_\(i)")!)

    }

}

func fillOptionArray() {

    randomOption32 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(15))
    randomOption = Int(randomOption32)

    for var i = 1; i <= 14; i++ {

        optionArray.append(UIImage(named: "option_\(randomOption)\(i)")!)

    }
}

func fillOutroArray() {

    for var i = 1; i <= 11; i++ {

        outroArray.append(UIImage(named: "outro_\(randomOption)\(i)")!)
    }

}


func clearArrays() {

    optionArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    optionArray = []
    outroArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
    outroArray = []
    imageViewOutlet.animationImages?.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    imageViewOutlet.animationImages = []

}
```

Thats pretty much my whole viewController.swift.

Edit:

So it turns out that my real problem is not the array but the way that iOS caches the images when using image named. I have since switched to using imagewithcontentsoffile, which seems to work for most people, and it does help, but doesn't entirely resolve my issue. I'm adding an array of about 100 images at a time to uiimageview.animation images. This animation will be played and swapped out with another 100 images very rapidly, but I can't clear animationimages, so every time I add a new array, it just appends on to the old one no matter how hard I try to clear animationimages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you exactly want but maybe this code could help you. I add 3 image in consecutive order just like you want,

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "image\(i).jpg")
```

with this line, i can access my image without putting in an array. I think you can access in animation as well.

Here's the full code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
                var x = 50
                super.viewDidLoad()
                for(var i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
                    var cgfloatx = CGFloat(x)
                    var myImage = UIImage(named: "image\(i).jpg")
                    var myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100 + cgfloatx, 90, 90))
                    myImageView.image = myImage
                    self.view.addSubview(myImageView)
                    x += 100
                }
            }
```

I hope i understood your problem correct, but next time, try to do something by coding, then ask here what's wrong in my code. I got lots of negative points just like asking question like yours.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am going to experiment with your code and try to better understand how it works to see how it can help me.  I also appreciate the tip about my post.  I wanted to include my initial code, but it had turned into a nightmare after trying to figure this out over about 10-15 different attempts to fix this yesterday.  I didn't even know which one was closest at that point.  Hopefully my recent edit on my post will help.

Comment: I was not able to get the above code to do what I intended.  I want an image to stay in the middle of the screen, and update one frame at a time.  This code moved my image.  Even when removing the change in x value, it didn't animate in place, it just happens so fast that it immediately displayed the last image in the animation.  I messed with NSTimer, but I haven't had much luck with timers working just right for animations like this and I feel that there is a better way to do a simple animation like this.  With that being said, I appreciate your suggestion, it taught me something new.